# Getting error on calling function from jquery ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a function from jquery ajax success. That function is for summation of input field value. It's completely fine if I not use function. But problem is when I use and call function. Here is my code

```
success: function (response) {
          if (response==0){
              alert('Item not found');
              $("#add_item").val("");
          }
          else {
              $('.item-content').append(response);
              $("#add_item").val("");
              sum_price();
          }
        }  

 function sum_price() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.per_item_price').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
    document.getElementById("total_tk").innerHTML = sum_price;
}
```

It appends in html

> **Total : function sum_price() { var sum = 0; $('.per_item_price').each(function() { sum += Number($(this).val()); }); document.getElementById("total_tk").innerHTML = sum_price; }** not value

Comment: `.innerHTML = sum_price;` <-- you are setting it to the function! The variable is `sum`

Comment: It does not append any value. it append code of function

Comment: oh..... got it. thanks a lot